# Firebase for Mobile Users can't return whitelist

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building apps on iOS and Android using Firebase auth and I'm having a hard time getting it to work out. This is my function to check if a user's UID is on the whitelist in my database. After this function is called in `viewDidLoad(_:)` it will get past the guard statement then exit the function without entering the completion block.

```
func checkUserAgainstDatabase(completion: (success: Bool) -> Void) {
    guard let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser else { return }
    FirebaseController.ref.child("users").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (data) in

// This is where the function exits and the program continues running.

        let uid = data.childSnapshotForPath(currentUser.uid)
        if uid.exists() {
            completion(success: true)
        } else {
            completion(success: false)
            currentUser.deleteWithCompletion(nil)
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the call in `viewDidLoad(_:)`:

```
UserController.shared.checkUserAgainstDatabase { (success) -> Void in
    if !success {
        self.showLoginSignUpView()
    }
}
```

Here are my rules on the database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I spent all day since posting this trying to do a whitelist solution and couldn't get it to work. However, a friend of mine sent me a solution similar to this and it works like a charm.

```
func checkUserAgainstDatabase(completion: (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    guard let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser else { return }
    currentUser.getTokenForcingRefresh(true) { (idToken, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(success: false, error: error)
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            completion(success: true, error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```